# Using Flow on SharePoint 2016 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, flow

We are using SharePoint 2016 on prem, and need to create some workflows, and are thinking about using Flow instead of the old SharePoint workflows.

I have googled a lot, and it looks like Flow can not be directly used on SharePoint 2016 on - prem, and that it has to be set up in the cloud (O365). Have I miseunderstood something here, or is this a fact ?

A little stupidly formulated question, but... How can I use flow if we don't want to use cloud services ? Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Flow is a cloud service. You can use it against SharePoint 2016 however you must deploy the [Data Management Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem) and use that gateway when making connections from Flow.

There are limitations when using the Data Management Gateway with SharePoint 2016; namely (last I tried) it could not resolve MMS fields.

SharePoint 2010 Workflows may be a better option for various tasks, but you can do a lot with Flow and SharePoint 2016. You'll need to evaluate on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. So, basically I need O365 and on-premises license to use Flow with on-prem, or hybrid environment ?

Comment: Yes, It's correct!