# Easy sync sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, sync

I have sharepoint 2016 in azure cloud (installed on VM in the cloud). I have 2 custom lists  in the same site collection - list A and list B with the same collumns.  I need to sync any changes on items (added, deleted, updated) made in list A to list B. Is there any OOTB solution (also interested on SP2019)?
So far i checked:

- MS Flow - i have account to Office365, can start to build Flow but it says the site collection is not available (although it's reachable on public internet)... how can i use the ms flow?
- I may implement a small app in C# using CSOM and schedule to perform sync lets say every 5 min. Or maybe create event handlers - how can I deploy them to the server?
- any other idea? use SP Designer 2013 to create workflows

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the SharePoint 2016 farm is built in the VM, you cannot use your O365 flow service in a different on-premise farm.

> Microsoft Flow is a cloud service. You can use it against SharePoint
>   2016 however you must deploy the Data Management Gateway and use that
>   gateway when making connections from Flow.
>
> There are limitations when using the Data Management Gateway with
>   SharePoint 2016; namely (last I tried) it could not resolve MMS
>   fields.

Reference:[Using Flow on SharePoint 2016 on prem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253138/using-flow-on-sharepoint-2016-on-prem)

For updating list item in another site collection, it may be better to build a workflow calling HTTP service and use the rest api to update.

Examples:

https://www.portiva.nl/nl/portiblog/2017/07/26/checking-out-and-updating-items-in-another-site-with-sharepoint-2013-workflow-and-the-rest-api

http://www.advaiya.com/blog/sharepoint-list-workflow-create-or-update-list-item-on-another-sharepoint-site-list/

https://www.portiva.nl/nl/portiblog/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection